# VB Saving img file with path adds folder name to file name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing

Hi I am having some problems with saving img files using Visual Basic, the files are being named wrongly with the folder name being added to the start of the file name.

I parse a web address and then use the split address values to rename my files however the the path value seems to be added to the file as well.

The files in the photo should be named for example "DCAT040iMBE Test13.jpg" 
but this file is being name "Test1DCAT040iMBE Test13.jpg"

[image]

```
Protected Sub GeneratedCode()
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Grey\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\QRCodeGenerator\QRCodeGenerator\Output\"
    LogoUpload.SaveAs(path + LogoUpload.FileName)
    TextFile.SaveAs(path + TextFile.FileName)
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path + TextFile.FileName)
    For Each line As String In lines

        Dim count As Integer
        Dim encoder As New QRCodeEncoder()
        encoder.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.H
        encoder.QRCodeScale = 10

        Dim img As Bitmap = encoder.Encode(line)
        Dim logo As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path + LogoUpload.FileName)
        Dim left As Integer = (img.Width / 2) - (logo.Width / 2)
        Dim top As Integer = (img.Height / 2) - (logo.Height / 2)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

        Dim parseLine = line
        Dim replaceDelimiter As String
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
            replaceDelimiter = Replace(line, "&", "=")
        End If

        Dim fileNameSplit() As String = replaceDelimiter.Split("=")
        Dim newFileName As String

        Dim partTwo = fileNameSplit(1)
        Dim partSix = fileNameSplit(5)

        Dim objFSO
        Dim newFolder As String
        newFolder = "C:\Users\Grey\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\QRCodeGenerator\QRCodeGenerator\Output\" + partSix
        objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(newFolder)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder)
        End If

        count += 1
        g.DrawImage(logo, New Point(left, top))
        newFileName = partTwo & " " & partSix & count & ".jpg"

        img.Save(newFolder + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        amountCreatedLbl.Text = count & " QRCodes Created"
        logo.Dispose()
    Next

End Sub
```

Could it be that I am generating my newFolder Values wrongly?

edited to add an example of data from the parsed txt file.

> ```
>   https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DTAT050&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test1
>     https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DCAT055iMB&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test1
>     https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DCAT040iMBE&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test1
>     https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DTAB060&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test1
> ```

```
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DTAT050&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test2
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DCAT055iMB&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test2
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DCAT040iMBE&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test2
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DTAB060&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test2

    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DTAT050&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test3
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DCAT055iMB&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test3
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DCAT040iMBE&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test3
    https://mywebsite.com/QRCode/default.aspx?materialcode=DTAB060&Logo=MyLogo&Companyloc=Test
```

Comment: Do you have a few lines of sample data from the file you are reading in and splitting apart?

Comment: HI RianBattle thanks for responding I've added a snippet of sample data from the text file I am parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a slash on the line:

```
img.Save(newFolder + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

It should be:

```
img.Save(newFolder + "\" + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The program doesn't realize that the newDirectory variable is supposed to be a directory, it's just being concatenated to the filename directly. A better option would be to use:

```
img.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(newFolder, newFileName), ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The `System.IO.Path.Combine()` function automatically adds the missing slash between the directory and filename, as well as some additional checks to make sure the result is valid.

As a side note, I would also recommend using & instead of + when joining strings together. Hard to debug issues can come up when you do it that way. I would also recommend turning `Option Strict On`, you will see a couple of other warnings that come up with your code as is. But, to resolve your issue, the above will work.

Comment: Hi RianBattle I just noticed this to thanks for you help I've marked it as the answer. thanks again.

Comment: @GreyWalker No problem, glad I could help!